# SwiftUI: showing keyboard in a tab view adds a weird space below second tab view

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-tabview

This sounds a bug in SwiftUI's `NavigationView` and `TabView`, when I have a `TabView` with (let's say) 2 tabs, the first tab has a `TextField` and the second tab has a `NavigationView`, follow these steps to produce the bug:

1. show the keyboard by tapping on the text field.
2. press on the "Return" button to hide the keyboard.
3. go to tab 2.
4. notice the weird bottom added space below the view, which approximately equals the height of the keyboard.

**-Note1**: if you do any of the following the bug won't be reproduced:

1. once the app launches, open tab 2, return to tab 1 and show the keyboard.
2. remove `NavigationView` from tab 2
3. show the keyboard one more time in tab 1

**Note2:**
I use `GeometryReader` in tab 2 to show the whole view area by a yellow color.

working code sample (just copy-paste it to try):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            View1()
                .tabItem { Text("View1") }
                .tag(1)
            
            View2()
                .tabItem { Text("View2") }
                .tag(2)
        }
    }
}

struct View1: View {
    @State private var myText = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("this is view 1")
            TextField("Enter Value", text: $myText)
        }
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { reader in
                Text("this is view 2")
                    .onAppear{
                        print("view 2 on appear")
                    }
            }
            .background(Color.yellow)
        }
    }
}
```

screenshot:

[image]

Is there a way to workaround this problem without having to remove the `NavigationView`, I tried every possible solution but couldn't a find a clue to avoid it ?

Comment: there's also another related bug here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64027482/onappear-calls-unexpectedly-when-keyboard-appears-in-swiftui and I reported it back to Apple FB8646389 but didn't get resolved for about a year now

Comment: I submitted a feedback to Apple: `FB9069933`